# Establishing Connection Between the Players in GameCenter

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5, xcode4.2, game-center

IOS 5
Xcode 4.2

I am working on GameCenter , I have followed raywenderlich tutorial and done the basic things of authenticating local users and so.., Now that i have to establish connection between the Players i am unable to get which part of code i should integrate, Most **importantly** i am not using Cocos 2D, and will not use that, 
Once if the Connection is Established, how do i pass data between the users.

Can anyone Kindly do help me to sort out this problem..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

There's a great tutorial by Ray Wenderlich about creating multiplayer game via Game Center.
I gladly recommend that you see it , it'll help you understand the way data is being transferred once the connection is established, and in generally the way Game Center works.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3325/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-22

Comment: @Shahar Biran: Yes, i had been following those tutorials and had completed, anyhow thank you for the answer.

Comment: regardless the fact that you're not working with cocos2d and the tutorial includes cocos2d, i thought it could help .....